# firebase simple email password authentication

Tags: authentication, firebase

I'm trying to use the 'rememberMe' option for Firebase simple EMail/Password login. But I cannot make it work and I don't really understand what must done.

Here's the code I use:

```
$('#btn-sign-in').click( function(e){
    var email = $('#login-user').val();
    var password = $('#login-password').val();

    authClient.login('password', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        rememberMe: true
    });
});
```

How is the 'rememberMe' option supposed to work ?

Answer (score 4):

[Engineer at Firebase here] The `rememberMe` option in Firebase Simple Login extends the default session length to 30 days. This happens automatically, and is technically enabled by generating session tokens (and storing them in the user's localStorage) for that extended period of time.

Can you clarify the problem that you're seeing? Keep in mind that in order to use this featureset, you must have enabled password authentication in Forge (accessible at https://YOUR-FIREBASE.firebaseIO.com), and, in your code, instantiated the FirebaseAuthClient with a callback to monitor the authentication state of your users, as described on https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html.

After a user logs in the for the first time, the callback you passed to `new FirebaseAuthClient(function(error, user){..})` will be invoked with `error=null` and a user object. After refreshing the page, this callback will again be invoked with the user object, as long as the 30-day session is still active.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast answer.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast answer.

Using your information I've done more tests and it appears that the 'rememberMe' option behavior depends upon the browser:

- Mac OSX/Safari 6.0.3: works fine
- Mac OSX/Chrome 26.0.1410.43: the authentication callback is never fires
- Mac OSX/Firefox 19.0.2: works fine
- Windows 7/Chrome 26.0.1410 : the authentication callback is called but user is null
- Windows 7/Firefox 19: works fine

For now, I'll hide the 'remember me' login checkbox for Chrome and I'll continue testing Firebase which is really awesome.

Comment: @kimbui You shouldn't have any of these problems, and behavior should be consistent across modern browsers. Please ping me directly so that we can investigate and get it resolved (rob <at> firebase.com).

Comment: I think I've found why the behavior was not consistent: I was using a local file system file url instead of a regular http:// url. Chrome might behave differently from other browsers when running from a local file. The 'RememberMe' options works fine with Chrome and http:// urls.

Comment: @kimbui Great, glad to hear it! Feel free to ping me if you encounter any other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem above, and kimbui is correct that it is directly related to using "file://" type URLs in Chrome. The localStorage object is unavailable for writes in that situation, but fails SILENTLY. As such, Firebase believes that is has successfully stored the session info, but on refresh, it's not there. If you deploy your code to Apache localhost or any other proper webserver, everything works perfectly.

Not sure if there's anything Firebase can do to sniff this issue out and perhaps error out to the console, but many thanks to kimbui for sniffing out the answer.